# Psychological abuse in Parasite?

Tags: plot-explanation, parasite

I am doing a project to identify the types of abuses in the movie Parasite. I have chosen Psychological abuse, which means manipulating the victim's mind for something. Would the Kim family pretend that they aren't related and that they are good chauffeurs, maids, art teacher, and tutor an example of psychological abuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convincing someone that you are a good fit for a job in which you're under qualified isn't psychological abuse.  Pretending that the person you are trying to have hired also isn't really psychological abuse either.  You might want to start looking in the direction of how they manipulated the mother into firing the maid.  If you recall what happened there, that's a good example of psychological abuse!